# Error while saving data in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am able to upload the file in the directory with a unique name but nothing gets saved in the database. Please help me to point out the mistake in the code.

```
<?php 
function findext ($filename) 
{ 
$filename = strtolower($filename); 
$exts = split("[/\\.]", $filename); 
$n = count($exts)-1; 
$exts = $exts[$n]; 
return $exts; 
}

$ext=findext($_FILES['photo']['name']);
$name=basename($_FILES['photo']['name'],$ext).'_'.rand(1000,9999).'.'.$ext;
$target='Resume/'.$name;

//This gets all the other information from the form 

$Name=$_POST['Name'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$CV='________/'.$target;

// Connects to your Database 
mysql_connect("localhost", "", "") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

//Writes the information to the database 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `candidate` VALUES ('$Name','$phone','$email','$CV')") ; 

//Writes the photo to the server 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
{ 
echo "Thank You for submitting your CV. We or Employers would revert to you shortly."; 
} 
else 
{  
echo "Thank You for submitting your information. However, you didn't upload your CV."; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: `mysql_connect("localhost", "", "") or die(mysql_error()) ; ` you didn't mention user in mysql connect

Comment: can you show some error code?

Comment: I mentioned the user and password as "data_new" and "datanew" and both the correct. I donot get any error message. But when I check the database, no new data gets saved.

Comment: How many fields are there in DB table?

Comment: there are 5 fields in the table.
CID - Auto increment
name, phone, email, cv

Comment: @souravnetwork Remove `single queto` from `php variablw`

Comment: Please try this mysql_query("INSERT INTO `candidate` VALUES ({$Name},{$phone},{$email},{$CV})");

Comment: @Lakhan That query won't work because there's no quotation marks around the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper concatenation must be done in order to produce the correct query and if only less fields are added just say what are they

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `candidate` (name,phone,email,cv) VALUES ('".$Name."','".$phone."','".$email."','".$CV."')") ;
```

Comment: if you want to omit the column-names part, you need to insert a `null` as well at the auto-incremented CID's place

Comment: Thanks ("INSERT INTO `candidate` (name,phone,email,cv) VALUES ('".$Name."','".$phone."','".$email."','".$CV."')")... did the trick. Thanks once again.